# Getting the input request in a Input Box prompt from a powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell converted into a EXE for ease of work for some powershell. The EXE is defined in a way that its hidden so i am not able to do the same for script that requires input. Can this be possible that the shell throws a input box where i can input the data?

Powershell command isas mentioned

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
Set-Mailbox
```

So if i convert this in a EXE and run it in a hidden mode i wont get a chance to add the mailbox name.

I can use Set-mailbox - indentity "Username" but since there are lot of users it makes it easy if i run it this way

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking to have the PowerShell script prompt the user with a message box for some input, rather than entering it at the console (since there's not visible console). Is that correct?

You *might* be able to accomplish this by using the old VB prompt box. Something like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
$mailbox = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter mailbox name", "Mailbox")
```

Comment: Yes you got that right thankyou sof your help. So i have to use powershell and a VB to get the prompt?i am not into VB so much so can you help me with this more. Thanks again!!

Comment: When i enter "Set-mailbox" I have to add " Identity" this is where i can enter  mailbox name so how can i add the VB on this ?

Comment: The code above will set the value of the $mailbox variable to whatever the user types in the box. If you wanted to pass it to Set-Mailbox's Identity parameter, it'd be something like:

Set-MailBox -Identity $mailbox